# Line break in fwrite

Tags: php, html, comments, fwrite

I have currently been developing a comment system and am using fwrite to display the comments in real time. Unfortunately i cannot work out how to put in linebreaks. I am using the code below:

```
$fp = fopen("log.html", 'a');
fwrite($fp, "<div class='msgln'>(".date("g:i A").") <b>".$_SESSION['fullname']."</b>: ".stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($text))."<br></div>");
fclose($fp);
```

Any idea,
Thanks

Comment: I'm not kicking for points here, but there are a few answers given below, including one of mine where I've made a few edits since my initial post. You may have thought that you had to replace the `<br>` with `\n`, where in fact you may not need them, but by adding `"\n"` at the end of your closing div. Do reload it and let us know about it since we've yet to have any feedback. I've done what I could to provide you with a solution. There is another answer stating the `\r\n` if you're on a Windows server which should be used.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned before `\n` on Linux

and/or

`\r\n` on Windows

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `"\n"` as line breaks when writing to files, rather than `<br>` tags. If the `<br>` tag(s) is/are required (*which seems to be the case here* - consult my ***sidenote*** about this below), then keep them and add the `"\n"` at the required place in your code that you want line breaks in, which I feel should be at the end of your closing div.

The double quotes for the `\n` is important here and not using single quotes `'\n'`. Otherwise it will literally enter `\n` in your file such as `</b>: Hello world<br></div>\n`

So you could do:

```
... ($text))."<br></div>" . "\n");
```

to produce something similar to:

```
<div class='msgln'>(1:29 PM) <b>John Doe</b>: Hello world<br></div>
<div class='msgln'>(1:35 PM) <b>Jane Doe</b>: Hello world<br></div>
```

**Sidenote:** You may not need the `<br>` tag in your code.

Using `... ($text))."</div>" . "\n");` will produce something similar to:

```
(1:49 PM) John Doe: Hello world
(1:55 PM) Jane Doe: Hello world
```

while viewed in a web browser and shown as seperate lines.

With the HTML source reading as:

```
<div class='msgln'>(1:49 PM) <b>John Doe</b>: Hello world</div>
<div class='msgln'>(1:55 PM) <b>Jane Doe</b>: Hello world</div>
```

Plus, since you are using sessions, make sure the session was started inside all files using sessions.

- `session_start();` is required to be on top of your PHP.

Comment: as noted in the other answer. use `\r\n` if you're on a Windows platform.